# Array to table HTML output

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i have a question here...

i have an array from mysql like this...

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Delivery"
    ["namaShipp"]=>
    string(3) "JNE"
    ["price"]=>
    string(5) "30000"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "Installation"
    ["namaShipp"]=>
    string(7) "Kudamas"
    ["price"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "Installation"
    ["namaShipp"]=>
    string(5) "MTECH"
    ["price"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

and then i want output it to a simple table.. and i dont know how..
So the result is grouped by ['name'] key.
My question is how to output that array to become like this

```
-----------------------------
INSTALLATION (get from ['name'])
----------------------------
MTECH - 0                <---- MTECH is get from ['namaShipp'] and 0 is from ['price']
KUDAMAS - 0

-----------------------------
DELIVERY
-----------------------------
JNE - 30000
```

Anybody can help please?? i will appreciate that..
i've just very confused about thisss...

thanks before

Comment: in your query, group by name

Comment: @Ibu: groupby does not yield the records but summaries.

Comment: is it okey for you to change the current structure of array to a structure you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$current=false;
foreach($result as $item)
{
  if($item['name']!==$current)
  {
    echo '
---------------------
'.$item['name'].'
---------------------';
    $current=$item['name'];
   }
   echo '
'$item['namaShipp'].' - '.$item['price'];
}
```

Comment: In this case, don't forget to primarily ORDER BY name.

Comment: @Lewyx OP mentioned the result is grouped by name

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming your array you showed is `$processedArray`):

```
$processedArray = array();
foreach ($mainArray as $innerArray) {
    $processedArray[$innerArray['name']][] = $innerArray;
}
foreach ($processedArray as $name => $itemsArray) {
    echo '----<br />'.$name.'<br />---';
    foreach ($itemsArray as $item) {
        echo $item['namaShipp'].' - '.$item['price'].'<br />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Transform your array! Create an array of arrays of records:

```
$list=array();    
foreach($data as $item)
    $list[$item['name']][]=$item;
foreach($list as $groupname=>$records){
    echo '--------------- '.$groupname.' ------------';
    foreach($records as $item){
        //output one $item as before...
    }
}
```